# NO_CI flag with Hudson

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, hudson, nant

I'm currently automating my project builds with Hudson + TFS + Nant and is all working great!. I have a build.properties.xml flag that is inside the workspace and it allows me to set the last build number, and some configurations I need. So as the last build step, I checkout the file and do a checkin.

And since my project is configured to Poll SCM every 10 minutes, Hudson always detects that there is a checkin in the workspace and kicks off a build.

I read that if I put the text ***NO_CI*** as part of the check in comment, then the build would not be triggered. But that doesn't work! I put it in the beginning, in the end and it always spans a new build.

I'm guessing that this is actually something TFS Builds do on their own, so that's why the Hudson TFS plugin does not comply with this.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspect, the ****NO_CI**** comment is a Team Build specific feature and the Hudson TFS plugin doesn't currently support it. I see you've created [an issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10960) on the Jenkins site for it already.

Hopefully they'll get it done for you quickly, though in the spirit of open source, you could always fork the the code on github, add the comment filter yourself (which should be very easy) and then submit a pull request to get the changes back into the main code base.